# Cheapshark API: reading NSDictionary without a key

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have been playing around with the [Cheapshark API](http://www.cheapshark.com/api/) and came up with this code:

```
- (IBAction)sendRequest:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cheapshark.com/api/1.0/deals?storeID=6&desc=0&title=civilization%20V&pageSize=2"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSError *requestError;
    NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;

    NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];        
    NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
}
```

Looking at the debugger I can see that the NSDictionary results has this value:

```
(lldb) po results
<__NSArrayM 0x17004aaa0>(
{
    dealID = "exhfdIoNgaoB4ieTIZi30ObELpggqQ9B9hpkSnN5rl0%3D";
    dealRating = "0.0";
    gameID = 106353;
    internalName = SIDMEIERSCIVILIZATIONVTHECOMPLETEEDITION;
    lastChange = 1412962351;
    metacriticLink = "/game/pc/sid-meiers-civilization-v-the-complete-edition";
    metacriticScore = 0;
    normalPrice = "49.99";
    releaseDate = 1392076800;
    salePrice = "49.99";
    savings = "0.000000";
    storeID = 6;
    thumb = "http://www.gamersgate.com/img/boximgs/small/DD-CIV5CE.jpg";
    title = "Sid Meier's Civilization V: The Complete Edition";
},
{
    dealID = "KvMAVxjVD4GOORbG2LPd%2FYy6ZVpyAyZPj%2FCiS0nwOhQ%3D";
    dealRating = "0.0";
    gameID = 61;
    internalName = SIDMEIERSCIVILIZATIONV;
    lastChange = 1412962393;
    metacriticLink = "/game/pc/sid-meiers-civilization-v";
    metacriticScore = 90;
    normalPrice = "29.99";
    releaseDate = 1285027200;
    salePrice = "29.99";
    savings = "0.000000";
    storeID = 6;
    thumb = "http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/8930/capsule_sm_120.jpg?t=1414605253";
    title = "Sid Meier's Civilization V";
}
)
```

But how do I go about accessing any of the individual values? There doesn't seem to be a key for me to find values for in the dictionary. How do I access the individual elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the results from response1 is an array, so the following code should help

```
NSArray *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    for(NSDictionary* dict in results){
        for(NSString* key in dict.allKeys){
            NSLog(@"keys :%@ ,value: %@",key,[dict objectForKey:key]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API `allKeys` to get an array of keys and access each one by one in a loop.

```
NSArray *keys = [myDictionary allKeys];
```

In your case

```
for (int i = 0; i < [results count]; i++ ) {
    NSArray *allkeys = [[results objectAtIndex:i] allKeys]; // you will get the keys list
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried 
NSArray *keys = [results allKeys];
but I got an unrecognised selector sent to instance error

Comment: This is because the response is an Array of Dictionary. You need to access each array element and then the dictionary.

Comment: @user2071152 - the response is started with array not the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

for(NSDictionary* dict in results){
        [yourMutableArray addObject: dict];
    }
```